# question about hardware/interfaces/BroadcastRadio.cpp of AOSP

Tags: pointers

I'm developing SW using AOSP.
Looking at the code, I see something strange in the behavior. In the openSession method of the class, it assigns newSession, which is an sp, to mSession, which is a wp. However, newSession will be destroyed when the method ends. Therefore, if the method is called again, oldSession will always be nullptr. Is this a correct logical behavior?

```
Return<void> BroadcastRadio::openSession(const sp<ITunerCallback>& callback,
                                         openSession_cb _hidl_cb) {
    LOG(DEBUG) << "opening new session...";
    /* For the needs of default implementation it's fine to instantiate new session object
     * out of the lock scope. If your implementation needs it, use reentrant lock.
     */
    sp<TunerSession> newSession = new TunerSession(*this, callback);
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mMut);
    auto oldSession = mSession.promote();
    if (oldSession != nullptr) {
        LOG(INFO) << "closing previously opened tuner";
        oldSession->close();
        mSession = nullptr;
    }
    mSession = newSession;
    _hidl_cb(Result::OK, newSession);
    return {};
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/master/broadcastradio/2.0/default/BroadcastRadio.cpp

Thank you.

want to know that is right code